# Wordpress showing Viagra

Tags: wordpress

We got the below email and of course we think its spam, but I just tried the search they said on google "site:pegstar.net viagra" ( https://www.google.com/search?num=100&site=&source=hp&q=site%3Apegstar.net+viagra ) and it does list these results. I have searched all posts and pages and can not find these. If I click on the link in the google search results I get page not found. Google Cache shows the data but its not in our layout and says it was from March 2016. How can I find out where this issue is coming from?

- I have checked .htaccess file and nothing would cause this
- I have upgraded to the newest wordpress version

[image]

Comment: I would suggest starting by checking your .htaccess file and then your theme's functions.php file. If you Google "WordPress Hacked" you should find a bunch of information on how to deal with this. [Wordpress.org](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) has a page as well.

Comment: If the problem is in your theme's functions.php file then in my experience there will be a really long line of code that is at the beginning or end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

There was a ton in the site, really the best solution is to uninstall and delete everything and then manually install wordpress and then download each plug and reinstall. Do not use copys of files you had as it injected itself into a TON of random files.